# IntelliJ and Android SDK sample projects

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Can IntelliJ use an Android SDK sample project as a base when creating a new project? So far, I haven't been able to import source codes from the default directory (`/samples/android-<level>/project_name`) and I had to copy the source files manually into a newly-created project.

Any faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to create project from existing sources. Here is [official documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-new-project-from-existing-source-code.html). If I understand correctly what do you mean. However if you want to use some project as a template then this will not suit you.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there's a way to copy files from another project into a new project automatically, while this creates a new project inside the source files folder. Can it be done?

Comment: @askmo, I've never managed to make Idea use some project as a template. As a workaround I used and SCM (SVN). I do this in two steps: 1) export template from the SCM (`svn export ...`) 2) create project from existing sources. However this resembles copying very much. I wont say there is no way to configure a template but If there is want to know it as much as you do.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that copying (or any other tool method like SVN) seems the best way. I do the same as you do but I thought there's a smarter way.